# Using numpy.random

Tags: python, numpy, noise, normal-distribution

I'm having a little bit of trouble using numpy.random.normal. At the bottom of this link (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) there's a graph which shows standard deviations. I'm a little confused about this, because it doesn't look like 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 etc. standard deviations. It also doesn't look like 1, 2, or 3 standard deviations.

What I'm trying to do is to add noise to an image at specific standard deviations. However, the results I get are honestly pretty weird. My code (in Python) is shown below:

```
poisson = float((raw_input("Noise standard deviation: ")))
.
.
.
name = t+'PHOTO'+s+str(i)+'.fits'

    im = pf.open(name)
    isinstance(im,list)
    im0 = im[0]
    poissonNoise = np.random.normal(0,poisson/1000, im0.data.shape).astype(float)
    test = im0.data + poissonNoise
    im0.data = test
    stringee = 'NOISE'
    pf.writeto(stringee+str(poisson)+name, data=test, clobber=True, header=im0.header)
print poisson
```

If you notice, I divide "poisson" by 1000 in order to get meaningful results. So what is the real value of the standard deviation, and how do I use it? All I want to do is to be able to input 1, 2, 3, etc. standard deviations and create that much noise.

Comment: In the example you linked, 0.1 was specified as the standard deviation of the desired distribution, so the values 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 on the X axis correspond to 1, 2, and 3 standard deviations. (Also, poissonNoise seems like a confusing variable name, when you're using a Gaussian distribution.)

Comment: What exactly does "im0.data.shape" do here?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're mixing things together. On the figure of discussion in the question

[image]

`X` axis is just `X` values **not** `Standard Deviations`. Remember that, for one distribution (here, `Normal`) there is only one **single value** standard deviation which can be computed easily, `numpy.std`.

BTW, your code is not quiet `Python` code. What is this: `isinstance(im,list)` for? Also remember that, indentation is heart of Python.